# How to detect search engines on Cloudfront?

Tags: seo, amazon-cloudfront

Is there a way to "ask" google to add a query string paramater to the url when crawling my website? (maybe in robots.txt?) so that when it crawls example.com, it would add something like ?iam=google . Because we use Cloudfront to serve our website, we need a way to detect search engines on the cloudfront and forward them to origin server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get Googlebot to add parameters.  Google does not support such functionality.

[Googlebot *does* send a `User-Agent` header](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en):

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
```

According to Google you are allowed to serve pre-rendered HTML content to Googlebot while serving the equivalent JavaScript to regular users. They call this [dynamic rendering](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/javascript/dynamic-rendering) and differentiate it from [cloaking](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355?hl=en) which is when sites show different content to Googlebot.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. We're not trying to cloak. The thing is the website uses javascript heavily, all the content is loaded via ajax so I was thinking I would make static version of the page for robots. Cloudfront doesn't forward the user agent header unfortunately.

Comment: I added a section to my answer about how to deal with JavaScript rendering in a situation like this.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Stephen Ostermiller is no longer true in 2022 as googles own developer website has published, that with spas you should serve a statically rendered site to google and a client-side rendered app to your users https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/javascript/dynamic-rendering

Comment: Nice find.  I updated my answer.